# L2スイッチを2台から3台にする場合の接続の仕方

Tags: network

ネットワーク初心者のため、御教示下さい。

24ポートL2スイッチ2台を使用し、19台のサーバーにLAN接続をしています。
（冗長化の為、1台のサーバーからそれぞれのスイッチに接続）

そのため、24ポートのうち19ポートはサーバー用に、2ポートはリンクアグリケーション用に使用済みの状況です。

しかし、新たにサーバーが10台増設されることになりました。
その場合、ポートが足りなくなってしまうので、1台スイッチを増設することになるかと思います。

3台構成になった場合、どのような接続の仕方になるのでしょうか。

（１）リンクアグリケーションは、以下のような接続になるのでしょうか？
　　　　　（スイッチ３）＝スイッチ１＝スイッチ２＝スイッチ３＝（スイッチ１）
　　　わかりづらくてすみません。
    スイッチ１と２をLAN2本で、２と３、３と１を同様に接続して輪になるようなイメージです。 
    リンクアグリゲーションもあまり詳しくは知らないため、3台で構成する場合はこのような接続になるのでしょうか？
    それともスイッチ１と３は接続不要で、１と２、２と３をつなげばOKなのでしょうか？
    そもそも3台では構成できないものなのでしょうか？

（２）配下のサーバーは現在は冗長化のため2個のスイッチに接続していますが、今後は3個中2個のスイッチに接続するイメージになるのでしょうか？

情報が不足していましたら、ご指摘ください。
どうぞアドバイスをお願い致します。

※要件があり、物理サーバーの仮想化はできません。
※使用するスイッチはメーカー指定があり、そのメーカーでは24ポート以上のものは扱っておりませんでした。

Comment: (1) がよく分からないんですが、3個のスイッチでループしようとしていますか？

Comment: わかりづらくてすみません。質問文を編集しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。既存のスイッチ2台=サーバー間の接続方法は何ですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。接続方法というのはLANケーブルでの接続ということでいいのでしょうか？

Comment: リンクアグリゲーションではないですよね。どうやってループを回避しているのか。それぞれタグ付きで別のサブネットに繋いでいたり。

Comment: スタック構成に対応しているかどうかなどで実現できる構成が変わってきます。既存の2台の機種と、指定されているメーカー名を追記してください。そうすれば、実現可能な構成がより具体的に示せると思います。そもそもSTPすら対応していないインテリジェントでは無いスイッチだとほとんどの回答が無駄になる可能性すらあります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> そのため、24ポートのうち19ポートはサーバー用に、2ポートはリンクアグリケーション用に使用済みの状況です。

本当にリンクアグリゲーションですか？(専用ポートを使用しない)スタック接続とリンクアグリゲーションによる接続は見た目では区別できません。サーバとの接続が複数リンクになっているようなのでこの違いは重要です。

リンクアグリゲーションによる接続なのであれば、論理的には単なるカスケード接続なので、追加するスイッチは同様にスイッチ1または2にカスケード接続する形に「たいてい」なります。「たいてい」なのは、後述するように設計を見直す必要があるかもしれないからです。

> （スイッチ３）＝スイッチ１＝スイッチ２＝スイッチ３＝（スイッチ１）

単純にこのようにつなぐとループします。STPで冗長構成にすることもできますが最近はあまり使わないです。

スタック接続の場合、

> (スイッチ３ - )スイッチ１ - スイッチ２ - スイッチ３( -スイッチ１)

このように接続するのが一般的です(リンクが1本になっているのに注意。リンクを2本にできるかは装置仕様によります)。

> （２）配下のサーバーは現在は冗長化のため2個のスイッチに接続していますが、今後は3個中2個のスイッチに接続するイメージになるのでしょうか？

サーバから3本出してそれぞれのスイッチに接続する構成とすることもないことはないです。OS、NICの仕様と用途次第です。

スイッチ間、サーバともどのように接続するかは、データの流れや故障時の動作を勘案して決めてください。サーバしかつながっていないということはないでしょうから、その部分の接続も再検討をしたほうがよいです。サーバ側の冗長構成とのからみもあります。

LAGにせよスタックにせよ装置の設定が必要になりますので、そういった部分も含めて設定してもらう業者と相談してください。必要であれば現状確認もしてもらってください。

Answer (score 1):

リンクアグリゲーションは2台のスイッチ間の物理的なリンクを論理的に1本にして負荷分散・冗長化する仕組みであり、3台の接続を一度に考えると混乱しますし、そのための仕組みではありません。

そのままズバリの良い記事があったので紹介します。
「リンクアグリゲーションとは」
https://news.mynavi.jp/kikaku/switch-6/

質問(1)の通りリンクアグリゲーションを構成するとループしますが、併せてスパニングツリープロトコルでブロッキングポートを設けるという紹介です。

また、高性能のスイッチは独自にスタッキングする機能を備えていて、複数台をあたかも1台のスイッチに見せることができます。
https://www.infraexpert.com/study/catalyst10.html

(2)はその通りです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。やはりNWは一朝一夕では難しいですね。
紹介いただいたページを拝見しましたが、以下のような構成で冗長化できるのかな・・・と思いましたが誤っていますでしょうか？
・負荷分散装置から、スイッチ3台にLAN接続する
・スイッチ１と２をリンクアグリゲーション、スイッチ２と３をリンクアグリゲーション
・配下の各サーバーは、3台のスイッチのうち2台にLAN接続

Comment: 負荷分散装置は質問に書かれていましたか？コメントで新しい質問をしないでください。

Comment: 「スイッチ１と２をリンクアグリゲーション、スイッチ２と３をリンクアグリゲーション ・配下の各サーバーは、3台のスイッチのうち2台にLAN接続」であれば、スイッチ2が壊れたときに、スイッチ1&2に接続されたサーバーと、スイッチ2&3に接続されたサーバーは疎通できません。つまり、冗長化できていません。その問題を解決するためにループ構成にしてスパニングツリーでブロッキング、ということになります。

Comment: すみません。余計な一文を記載してしまいました。
以後、注意いたします。